# Memory allocation problem

Tags: c++, windows-services, malloc, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a Windows Service that allocates memory dynamically. I tried both c++'s new operator and C's malloc. They return (probably valid) pointer but when I try to dereference it the program crashes with Windows saying:

> The instruction at "0x77c478ac"
>   referenced memory at "0x00cb9001". The
>   memory could not be "read".

BTW I guess the pointer is valid because the referenced memory is not NULL (0x00cb9001).

**EDIT**: Here is the code

```
/*  This is a thread procedure that is
    called when connection arrives
    and its purpose is to serve as a 
    regular expression server.
*/
void threadProc(LPVOID *ptr){
     SOCKET accSock = (SOCKET) *ptr;
     void * foundPtr;
     int recvdBytes;
     char * literalPtr;
     u_long iMode = 0;

     literalPtr = new char [4096];  //this may cause the problem
     //We allocate 4kb but in fact the first 2 kbs will be for
     //for the literal string, the next 2 kb are for the result
     //that must be returned
     ioctlsocket(accSock, FIONBIO, &iMode); //the "parent" socket was nonblocking

      if(literalPtr){

     recvdBytes = recv(accSock, (literalPtr+1), 2048, 0);   //BTW, recv returns -1

     foundPtr = regexp_cmp(literalPtr, fBuffer, 0); //program crashes when calling this function

     if(!foundPtr){
        *(literalPtr+2048) = (int) 0;
        send(accSock, (char *) (literalPtr+2048), 4, 0); //sending 4 NULLs   
     }
     else {
        send(accSock, (char *) (literalPtr+2048), 2048, 0);
}
   shutdown (accSock, 0);
   delete[] literalPtr;
   return;
}
```

Comment: You need to show the code involved, the pointer you're using is *definitely* not valid, if it were you wouldn't have a crash on your hand like you've shown.

Comment: Did you pass the pointer to a different process?

Comment: No. The allocation problem occurs in a thread and it doesn't pass the pointer to other threads or processes.

Comment: why do you pass (literalPtr+1) and not literalPtr to recv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty funny, you have the answer commented in your code. recv returns -1, indicating that no bytes were read and there is an error, (why not check errno and see what the problem is?) and then you call regexp_cmp anyway on an uninitialized buffer. No wonder it crashes.

As a second point, your code it overly complex. For example, the buffer size is fixed. Why bother newing it? You can keep the buffer on the stack. Why share the same buffer for two different purposes? Just allocate 2 buffers; one for send and the other for recv. Then you don't need to deal with possibly problematic pointer math.

Comment: I feel like a complete fool. I didn't think memory filled with zeros could raise such an exception...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `regexp_cmp(literalPt...` treats lineralPt as a string: that string is not null terminated ( I can't see any code effort to terminate that string ) so the function simply overrun that buffer looking for the '\0' that never comes...

Comment: 'regexp_cmp' really treats literalPtr as a string but in fact 'recv' doesn't work as expected - it returns -1 so I think the problem is with the new operator.

Comment: the new in order to me is ok. If you wanna go further just fill it with zeroes as just is allocated ( memset )

Comment: You don't have to use mender, you can ask new to initialize the buffer by new char[4096]();